# How to implement generator for this function?

Tags: python, generator, yield

For function `a(0) = 3, a(n) = 2*a(n-1) -1`, generator should be like:

```
def p():
    b = 3
    while True:
        yield b
        b = 2 * b -1
```

So for function `c(1) = 9, c(n) = 9*c(n-1) + 10**(n-1)- c(n-1)`,
how to write the generator for this function?

Comment: question is not clear. Can you elaborate with what you expect and what did you get with this code?

Comment: Show your own effort (code) properly formatted in the question. The main difference to shown example is that you have to remember and increment "n".

Comment: I would like to write a generator for the second function c(1) = 9, c(n) = 9*c(n-1) + 10**(n-1)- c(n-1). Format and method is similar to the first. I tried many times, but didn't get the right answer.

Comment: What is c(0)? What are the first few numbers?

Answer (score 0):

For the sequence, you have value for c(1) as 9, calculate the value for c(0) using c(1) which turns out to be 1, then write a generator which first yeilds c(0), and c(1), then for each next values, apply the formula, and get the next value and yield it, finally replace the previous value b0 by this next value b1 in order to continue the sequence.

```py
def generate_seq():
    b0 = 1
    b1 = 9
    n=2
    yield b0
    yield b1
    while True:
        b1 = 9*b1 + 10**(n-1) - b1
        yield b1
        b0 = b1
        n += 1
        
seq = generate_seq()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(seq))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
1
9
82
756
7048
66384
631072
6048576
58388608
567108864
```

Comment: b(0) should be 1, and b(1) = 9. why is your b(0) = 9 and b(1) = 1?

Comment: c(1) = 9 c(2) = 82 c(3) = 756 c(4) = 7048 c(5) = 66384 c(6) = 631072 c(7) = 6048576

Comment: The above are the right answer, which I check using recursion.

Comment: But I can not get them using generator.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your original, just the extra power of 10:

```
def p():
    c = 1
    pow10 = 1
    while True:
        yield c
        c = 8*c + pow10
        pow10 *= 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TaFAQ9OKSwEIkhVsFQzBrIL8ckMDOK88IzMnVSGkqDQVog4EKjNTc1IUkuF8kF4LrWQFbYheuDjEJC2gUQZcXGn5RUCFmXkIKwuKMvNKNJI1//8HAA)